# Mount Binding to move App data to External Memory

Tags: app2sd, mount, terminal, ext2

I recently came across the idea of mount binding in Linux. I am wondering if I can mount bind the `/storage/emulated/0/Android` to `/storage/sdcard1/Android`. Will this extend my internal storage?

Should I partition my sdcard into 2 partitions with one being ext2 file system for this to work?

Will apps whose data is stored in the internal memory work if I do this and then move the data to the external sdcard? Where will the apps I download in the future store their data?

Comment: [How to bind-mount “data” and “obb” folders from external SD card in “/sdcard/Android”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219514/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, partition the SD card into 2 *primary* partitions with one being ext2 and the other FAT32. Then download the newest version of Link2SD from Play Store, patch with Lucky Patcher's custom patch. When you load Link2SD, you'll be told if everything is set up right. If it doesn't say anything negative, then open the settings, and make sure to enable auto-link and a few other settings you'll notice you may want to enable. After that, set the default install location to the external SD, and then you're all set. For all the apps you already have installed, just change the filter so it displays the moveable ones (almost all will be) and touch each one, and hit link to SD.

The biggest thing to avoid while setting all this up is to not do any unnecessary actions other than what I just said. It's a simple process but if you are like me and think oh I better clean my Dalvik cache while I'm here in recovery mounting my card or hey I better uninstall Link2SD I already had and reinstall with an already patched ver, etc. keep it simple and what was said, you'll have no problems. Took me 3 days to get it to work. I was told exactly what I just told you and in the end that was exactly what I had to do to get it working.

Comment: Hi, I know about link2sd. I want specific answer to my question about mount binding. I an interested in knowing how to do this manually. Thanks for attempting to answer.

Comment: @GiantTree I want to manually bind mount an ext2 partition to increase my internal memory. The answer provided does not deal with the question. I can't accept this answer

Comment: If it's this then just unmount `/storage/emulated/0` and mount your own partition there. You might want to repeat that for all the other places where your internal SD is mounted (`/sdcard`, `/storage/emulated/legacy`, `/storage/sdcard0`)