# How to bind-mount "data" and "obb" folders from external SD card in "/sdcard/Android"?

Tags: external-sd, permissions, 9.0-pie, mount, bind-mount

Can someone help me mount my `Android/data` and `Android/obb` in my internal storage from my portable storage? I'm on a Pie ROM.
I found this: [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions) but I don't know what should I do.

When I type:

```
ls -dZ /sdcard
```

I get

```
u:object_r:rootfs:s0 /sdcard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-directories in `/sdcard/Android/data` or `/sdcard/Android/obb` (called apps' private directories on primary external storage) have **synthesized permissions based on directory structure**. While public directories on the rest of the `/sdcard` have fixed permissions. See details in [Android's Storage Journey](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) and [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526).

My answer to your linked question: [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526) addresses the latter case i.e. bind mounting public directories which are shared with all apps. But private directories cannot be bind-mounted from external storage with fixed permissions. However using the same approach you can bind-mount every app's private directory separately.

Let's take example of Termux app. Its private directories (`Android/data/com.termux` and `Android/obb/com.termux`) are owned by the UID of Termux app assigned at the time of installation. Common ways to get UID value is to read from `/data/system/packages.list` or do `ls -ld /sdcard/Android/data/com.termux` or using `stat` command. A simple approach is to bind-mount the directory as world-writable so that every app can write to it. But it's not a good idea to set such open permissions. So we go the Android's way; bind-mount a directory from external SD card using FUSE:

```
~# bindfs -u $(stat -c %u /sdcard/Android/data/com.termux) -g 9997 -p a-rwx,ug+rw,ug+X /mnt/media_rw/[UUID]/Android/data/com.termux /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Android/data/com.termux
```

- For further mount options and details see the above linked answer.
- Replace `/mnt/media_rw/[UUID]` with `/mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0` if SD card is formatted as Adoptable Storage but data is not *migrated*.
- In the same way `obb` directories can be bind-mounted.
- If your device supports `sdcardfs`, the same mount should propagate to `default` and `read` emulated *VIEWS* as well. Otherwise if your device is older you can bind-mount the same way to other *VIEWS*.
- Some apps by default prefer writing private data to secondary external storage (i.e. external SD card), so you don't need to bind-mount their `data` or `obb` directories.

Comment: when i use the code i get "Not a valid user ID: 10187" , i found the same user id in "ls -n /sdcard/Android/obb"

Comment: @mahanr please go through the linked answer once, I don't want to copy paste everything. You need to `touch` files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

Comment: @mahanr as per the [new change](https://github.com/mpartel/bindfs/issues/79) to `bindfs`, `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` is no more necessary. I'm adding the link to new binary in linked answer.

Comment: Can I mount whole obb folder?

Comment: @Jtnqr I can't think of a reason for it to not work. Just take care of the ownership, mode and SELinux context properly.

Comment: Should I use the command above then? or this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526 ?

Comment: @Jtnqr neither. You need to adapt the command according to your requirements.